# Does ASP.NET Session StateServer mode cache data on web server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, session-state

I'm using ASP.NET 5 Session in StateServer mode with a session state service running on a different machine. When all is working fine in the app, certain session objects are able to be accessed from the Session. However, when I restart the app, it appears that the user's session still exists, but certain objects throw an (de)serialization error when trying to get them from session. This leads me to believe that most of the time the session data is getting pulled from a local cache that doesn't serialize/deserialize the objects like the StateServer does... and then when the app restarts the local cache is lost, and so the objects have to get pulled from the StateServer, which then has problems deserializaing certain objects.

Can anyone confirm my hunch about Session caching when using StateServer mode in asp.net 5?

EDIT: I think I found the answer [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2004/Dec/22/ASPNET-Cache-and-Session-State-Storage):

> I was actually surprised to see the behavior exactly the same as with
>   InProc objects. Even though objects serialize ASP. Net tracks objects
>   locally and writes out any changes out to the stateserver.

Comment: "certain session objects are able to be accessed from the Session" Are those objects serializable?

Comment: @LexLi They are marked as serializable but have entity framework proxy navigation properties that cause an error when deserializing. No apparent error when adding to the Session (like what you get when the class isn't marked serializable), but throw an exception when materializing from the Session after the app restarts. Before the app restarts those same objects materialize from the Session without any problems.